# How can I access user data from my AuthController and grab the value in FileUploadController successfully?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

My ultimate goal's is that I'm trying to grab the `email` value inside the `login()` function in my `AuthController` and use it inside my `FileUploadController`.  But before I do that, I need to make sure I can access `user` but it won't let me.

I've tried to `put()` it in a session and `get()` the value but it keeps returning `null` in Postman upon running `dd($request->session()->get("user");` which shows me the user isn't authenticated.

But how's that possible when I'm successfully logging in on front end with user email and password?  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  Below's the code for reference.

`AuthController`:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);

    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();

    $request->session()->put("user", $user);

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        $user
    ]);
}
```

FileUploadController:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $data= ['file_path'=>$filePath, 'user_id'=>1];

    dd($request->session()->get("user"));

    DB::table('user.photos')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.";
}
```

Comment: `use Auth;` on the top then you can access by `Auth::user()->id;`,  `Auth::user()->email;`,  `Auth::user()->name;` you can get anything from `Auth` by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to use the Auth facade, which gives your access to the currently authorized user. You can use this directly in FileUploadController.

```
Auth::user()->email;
```